# How can we use url of datasource in kubernetes while creating configmap

Tags: kubernetes, configmap

How can we use url of  datasource in kubernetes while creating configmap
like 
ex. kubectl create configmap config-from-file --from-file=https://url-to-file-location

Answer (score 3):

No, currently it is not possible to *directly* use URL as source for a configMap property.

But this will do the trick:

```
kubectl create configmap config-from-url --from-literal=propkey="$(curl -k https://url-to-file-location)"
```

You can specify the namespace where to create the configMap with `-n` or `--namespace` - see `kubectl options`.

The `-k` option for `curl` allows connections to sites with untrusted (e.g. self-signed) certs.

Using `wget` instead of `curl` can be another option.

Comment: @ParamanandDhuri - If this answered the question (quote) "...How can we use url of datasource in kubernetes while creating configmap"...the etiquette is to accept the answer? ;-)

Answer (score 2):

kubectl doesn't support creating configmaps using urls
https://github.com/kubernetes/website/pull/9903